# Graphing Parametric Functions Ti-84 Plus CE

Tags: graphing-functions, parametric, calculator

I am currently studying for the Math 2 SAT and when dealing with Parametric equations I tend to graph them.

I recently tried graphing the parametric equation: `x = T^2 + T     y = T^2 - T`. [Original Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfW2p.png)

When graphing this on my Ti-84 Plus CE this is the graph that came up:
[Ti-84 Plus Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0VnG.jpg)

The correct graph that led to the correct answer in my book was: [Correct Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQyy4.png)

What could have possibly led to the graph being cut of, could it be that the domain was restricted?
And If so, are there solutions to view the whole graph?

Comment: It looks like your domain is restricted on your TI.  I don't have that particular calculator, but there should be a setting to adjust the domain of $t$.  Setting the domain to $[-3,3]$ should be enough.  See [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sdcvuwblfh)

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you @DMcMor